# Ubuntu installed successfully but not booting

Tags: windows

I have installed Ubuntu on my lappy alongside with Windows7 on DriveE (windows is in DriveC). when installing ubuntu it didn't ask any thing it ask only whether you want to install alongside with windows. I selected that option. there was message that installation was successful. After restarting it directly boots to windows it's not asking to select os and driveE which i have installed ubuntu is not visible.

please give solution to my problem

Comment: How did you installed ubuntu? are you using `wubi.exe`? or you are booting using a usb /cd

Comment: I have done installation through CD

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the Linux bootloader (GRUB). Looks like it isn't installed correctly.

To re install  GRUB you will need the live disk once again.

There are two ways,

**Manual Method,**

You can follow the great answer here - [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/q/88384/35775)

Though question is different, it is applicable for your case. In your case it should be `sda` not `sdb` as mentioned in answer step3.

**Also Step 7 is must** in this case.

**Easier way,**

You can use live disk & [`boot-repair`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool to perform a `Recommended Repair`.

Instruction are here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

At the end, it will generate a URL, please take a note of that URL. If after recommended repair, it doesn't load GRUB, please attach the URL in this question.