# Installed Ubuntu 16.04, but it isn't booting

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10. The installation got completed successfully and asked me to restart the pc. Upon restarting, I am being directed directly to Windows, and not getting the grub screen.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4vRH.jpg) is what the boot priority of my device looks like. Even if I go to the [BIOS menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OEl8.jpg) and manually select Ubuntu, it still goes to Windows 10.

Based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277350/ubuntu-installed-successfully-but-not-booting) answer, I tried `boot-repair` and performed a `Recommended Repair`. Here is the pastebin for the same: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/RhWftPQFcM/ . Unfortunately, the issue still persists.

Any help on this matter will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set grub as the standard boot option from Windows:

1. Open a CMD-prompt as **Administrator**
2. type `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` and hit Enter
3. reboot
   You should now get the Grub menu. To modify how grub behaves I would recommend using `boot-repair` and its `advances options`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I tried it and unfortunately, there is no difference - still no grub screen, and goes straight to windows. At this point, I am beginning to get skeptical if my ubuntu installation is alright. Although there was no error message while installation and everything seemed fine, is there a way I could check the installation itself? Thanks again for your time!

Comment: Did you install Windows first and then Ubuntu or the other way around?

Comment: I had windows 10 pre-installed and later installed Ubuntu 16.04 through a bootable usb.

Comment: Did you follow a guide? If so could you ad a link to you original question. The partitioning in the pastebin seem a bit weird to me but I never used 16.04 so that might be fine. Also is there a specific reason you are using such an old version? please be aware that it will become unsupported quiet soon (April 30, 2021).